# PHP syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using cakephp and php 5.3 and just recently I keep getting this weird error i'm not sure why :

> Error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION File: /Applications/AMPPS/www/gestionstock/server/app/Model/Work.php    Line: 2

here is the content of the file Work.php :

```
<?php 
 class Work extends AppModel{ 
    public $hasOne = array("Projet" , "Salarie" , "Ville") ; 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure we look at the correct file here?

Comment: @Rizier123 yes that's the same file, i keep getting this weird error on a lot of files , Sometime i delete the file and rewrite the exact same thing then the error is gone ... it's driving me crazy i'm not sure why this is happening

Comment: According to your code and to what you mentioned in your comment - it's seems that it's not related to your code. Maybe your editor's encoding, ftp upload, server's cache?

Comment: @OfirBaruch I'm trying this on my localhost there is no ftp upload involved in the process , I use sublime text 3 as my editor and I tried these encodings : UTF-8 , UTF-8 without BOM , ISO-8859 1 ans still same error , I'm not sure where to check for server's cache ?

Comment: Did you modify other files recently, perhaps another class file that you forgot to close the bracket for?

Comment: @sjagr I'm getting this on a new cakephp project there isn't much class files and all of them seems to be valid but just this error that keep on some new files

Comment: Open in incognito mode in your browser and try again.

Comment: @Johnwilliams problem is persistant even with incognito

Comment: Try clearing you app/tmp/ directory

Comment: @Johnwilliams that didn't work either !! what kind of sorcery is this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this error was generated because there was a space `' '` after `{` in line 2;

I'm not sure why this is an error , but removing the space solved my problem.